# Detecting dropped text into an input element?

Tags: javascript

and also rejecting non-text items.  This is so that a user can drag and drop text into input field.  If the user tries to input non-text it is not allowed.

Here is how to detect the drop event:

```
   input_element.addEventListener("drop", function (event) {

        // `this` points to the input element

        // implement is_text

        if (is_text) {
            label_element.style.opacity = 0;
        } else {
            // reject
        }
    }, false);
```

The label element opacity is set to 0 to make the label disappear.

How can I verify that the dropped "thing" is actually text?

this will point to

```
[Object HTMLInputElement]
```

`.value` holds the text if there is any.

Howerver this.value will not log correctly.  console.log(this.value) does not show the value even though the dom inspector does.

event holds

```
[ObjectDragEvent]
```

Comment: might be helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#drop

Comment: Not sure how you'd drop anything other than text in an input with the type text, even dropping an image seems to just end up with the image URL as a string in the input, but the `input` event will at least capture the value -> http://jsfiddle.net/DdbKD/1/

Comment: Sure, it's the `input` event, it's something that's available in newer browsers to capture any input, like keypress, paste etc. and it also seems to work for dropping, here's a plain JS one -> http://jsfiddle.net/DdbKD/2/

Comment: maybe something like this? (only tested on chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/DdbKD/3/

Comment: or something like this http://jsfiddle.net/DdbKD/4/ (without the timeout trick)

Comment: to reset the value of the input when dragging an image for example, but `event.preventDefault` does the trick too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can detect if the dropped data is text with `event.dataTransfer.types` of the drop event.

By trial and error I noticed it usually has `text/plain` and `text/html`. When dropping an image it has those types aswell, but also an extra one (some uri thing).

So you can do this:

```
input_element.addEventListener("drop", function (event) {
    var types = event.dataTransfer.types;

    if (types.length > 2 || types.indexOf("text/plain") === -1)
        event.preventDefault();
    else
        input_element.style.opacity = "0";
}, false);
```

Note that I only tested this on chrome. This could have different behaviour on other browsers. The `indexOf` method i'm using is not even supported in some IE versions.

The example: http://jsfiddle.net/DdbKD/4/

Comment: what are some example values of types?

Comment: the values of `dataTransfer.types` i managed to see were `["text/plain", "text/html"]`, `["text/plain"]`, `["text/plain", "text/uri-something" "text/html"]`. I can't recall exactly the `uri-something` one, but that was there when dropping an image. The common case seemed to be `text/plain` + `text/html` but `text/plain` was also possible if dropping text from a plain text editor.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = "some string";
if(typeof text == 'string') //true
```

you have to add the taxt to dataTransfer of dragged element by hooking to its dragstart or so.
Check http://html5demos.com/drag

```
addEvent(el, 'dragstart', function (e) {
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy'; // only dropEffect='copy' will be dropable
  e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id); // required otherwise doesn't work
});
```

As in above example link

But what are you trying to drag?

Comment: Then I think @adenos solution will help you

Comment: inspection of the event.dataTransfer from the drop event is all that is needed.